# Pandas Dataframe apply custom function to certain rows with NULL columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, sklearn-pandas, django-pandas

I have a Dataframe that looks like:

```
------------------------------
|Date       | Deal | Country |
------------------------------
|2019-01-02 | ABC  | US      |
------------------------------
|2019-02-01 | ABC  | US      |
------------------------------
|2019-03-03 | ABC  | US      |
------------------------------
```

Another Dataframe that looks similar with *Country* populated based on certain logic

```
------------------------------
|Date       | Deal | Country |
------------------------------
|2019-01-01 | ABC  | NaN      |
------------------------------
|2019-02-01 | ABC  | US      |
------------------------------
|2019-03-02 | ABC  | NaN      |
------------------------------
```

Notice that the dates are different. In the second Dataframe, I wish to populate the Null Country tags by referencing the latest Country tag from the first Dataframe, 
So I can do something like, 
searching the Deal in 1st Dataframe and sorting in descending order by date and getting the latest *Country* column to populate the 2nd Dataframe. 
However, this gets very slow for 2million+ rows....

Is there any better way to do this?

I tried `groupby(['Date', 'Deal']).agg(lambda x: sorted(x)[0])`
but can't merge with the 1st Dataframe because the Dates don't match. I just need to fill it with the nearest Country tag based on Date.....

Any pointers on this would be greatly appreciated! thanks in advance..

Comment: Will you please share df.head().to_dict () ?  It will give some sample data.

Comment: Sure, here is the data for 1st one
{'Country': {0: 'US', 1: 'US', 2: 'US'},
 'Date': {0: '2019-01-02', 1: '2019-02-01', 2: '2019-03-03'},
 'Deal': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC'}}


& the 2nd one

{'Country': {0: 'US', 1: 'US', 2: 'US'},
 'Date': {0: '2019-01-01', 1: '2019-02-01', 2: '2019-03-02'},
 'Deal': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC'}}

Comment: Do both tables have 2million + rows or is the second table much larger than the first?

Comment: 2nd table is actually smaller than 1st (50% smaller) 
so like 1 mil rows

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

tbl1 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': {0: 'US0', 1: 'US1', 2: 'US2'}, 'Date': {0: '2019-01-02', 1: '2019-02-01', 2: '2019-03-03'}, 'Deal': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC'}})
tbl2 = pd.DataFrame({'Country': {0: 'US', 1: np.nan, 2: np.nan}, 'Date': {0: '2019-01-01', 1: '2019-02-01', 2: '2019-03-02'}, 'Deal': {0: 'ABC', 1: 'ABC', 2: 'ABC'}})

print(tbl1)
print(tbl2)

t1_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(tbl1[['Deal','Date']])
tbl1.index = t1_index
tbl1.sort_index(inplace=True)

tbl2['country_filled'] = tbl2.apply(lambda row: row['Country'] if pd.notnull(row['Country']) 
                                    else tbl1.xs(row['Deal'],level='Deal').loc[:row['Date']]['Country'][-1],
                                    axis=1)

print(tbl1)
print(tbl2)
```

Sorting table 1 first before doing your look-ups rather than inside the agg function may help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) with the `method= 'nearest'` on 'Date' to find the closest date after merging by 'Deal' first. Then `fillna` the column country in `df2`

```
df2 = df2.fillna(pd.merge_asof(df2.drop('Country', axis=1), df1, 
                               by='Deal', # merge first on same Deal
                               on='Date', # merge on nearest date
                               direction='nearest')) #closest date
```